# Angular8: Global date format config

Tags: javascript, angular, date-formatting, angular8, angular-date-format

I am using Angular8 and want to format date and time but I have to use date pipe with same format pattern again and again as shown below

```
<p>{{ myDate | date: 'dd MMM yyyy, h:mm a' }}</p>
<p>{{ myOtherDate date: 'dd MMM yyyy, h:mm a' }}</p>
<p>{{ otherVar }}</p>
<p>{{ myOtherOtherDate date: 'dd MMM yyyy, h:mm a' }}</p>
```

and same format `date: 'dd MMM yyyy, h:mm a'` is to be used in each and every component of my project.

Is there a way where I can provide a global config in the providers of my App Module, something like this

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {provide: LOCAL_PIPE_DATE_PATTERN, useValue: 'ddMMyy'},
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and just use the date pipe as

```
<p>{{ myDate | date }}</p>
<p>{{ myOtherDate | date }}</p>
<p>{{ otherVar }}</p>
<p>{{ myOtherOtherDate | date:'MMyyDD' }}</p> (If format changed)
```

Comment: You can create a custom pipe that consumes `LOCAL_PIPE_DATE_PATTERN` and uses angular date pipe internally. This way you can as well include any other formatting that need to be added globally across your application, say if you want to add a prefix or suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a local DatePipe in your ts file and convert the date in the Format you use the most and the rest of the time use the Pipeline it self.

```
    yourNormalDateString : Date = new Date();
    datePipe = new DatePipe('YOUR_LOCAL_CODE');
    dateToDisplay = this.datePipe.transform(this.yourNormalDateString, 'Your Date Format String');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new date pipe in your project and initialize always the format

```
@Pipe({
    name: "myDate"
})
export class MyDatePipe {

    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

    transform(value: any): string {
        let format = "dd MMM yyyy, h:mm a";
        return this.datePipe.transform(new Date(value), format);
    }
}
```